# While implementing Data table in Spring Boot MVC Project with Thymeleaf ,no any data populate in data table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, datatables, thymeleaf

My Service,Controller and Views are :

> public class LoadDataService {

```
public List<Employee> getEmployeeList(){
    List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    Employee employee1 = new Employee("Sridharan","Junior Blogger","5000","India");
    Employee employee2 = new Employee("Arul Raj","Senior Blogger","105000","China");
    Employee employee3 = new Employee("Priya","Associate","21000","Australia");
    Employee employee4 = new Employee("Sam","Associate","20030","Australia");
    Employee employee5 = new Employee("Ram","Associate","2020","Australia")
    employeeList.add(employee5);
    employeeList.add(employee4);
    employeeList.add(employee3);
    employeeList.add(employee2);
    employeeList.add(employee1);
    return employeeList;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "LoadDataService [getClass()=" + getClass() + ", hashCode()=" + hashCode() + ", toString()="
            + super.toString() + "]";
}
```

}

Controller class :

@Controller
public class JQueryDatatableController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JQueryDatatableController.class);

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView home(Locale locale, Model model) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

    LoadDataService dataService = new LoadDataService();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();       

    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("employeeList", mapper.writeValueAsString(dataService.getEmployeeList()));        
    mav.setViewName("index");

    return mav;
}
```

}

data table integration in HTML thymeleaf page is :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Datables Demo</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js}" ></script>
        <script th:src="@{js/jquery.dataTables.js}"></script>
    
     <!--CSS StyleSheet -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/common.css}"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/jquery.dataTables.css}">
   
</head>
     
<body>
<div>
<img class="dataTableExample" th:src="@{/images/JQueryDatatableandSpringMVC.png}">
</div>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="overflow-x:auto">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Designation</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Country</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
   </table>
   

<script th:inline="javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
  
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "searching": true,
        "serverSide":false,
        "paging":true,
        "sAjaxSource":"${employeeList}",
        "columns": [
            {"data": "name"},
            {"data": "designation"},
            {"data": "salary"},
            {"data": "country"}
        ]
       
    })
});

</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBoKQ.jpg)

Comment: `sAjaxSource` takes an URL not a placeholder.

Comment: how cam i map sAjaxSource with employeelist in thymeleaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple try and reading a lot of problem ,i find the answer

```html
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">

  var empList = [# th:utext="${employeeList}"/]; 
  

$(document).ready(function () {
 
   console.log(empList); 
   
  
  $('#example').DataTable({
        "aaData":empList,
        "aoColumns": [
            {"mDataProp": "name"},
            {"mDataProp": "designation"},
            {"mDataProp": "salary"},
            {"mDataProp": "country"}
        ]
       
    }) 
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning Employee List to 'data' like below,

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

var empList = ${employeeList};

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#example').DataTable({
        "searching": true,
        "serverSide":false,
        "paging":true,
        "data": empList,
        "columns": [
            {"data": "name"},
            {"data": "designation"},
            {"data": "salary"},
            {"data": "country"}
        ]

    })
});

</script>
```

https://datatables.net/manual/data/

Comment: Still Not Working !!

Comment: I find the updated answer and posted in below post ..thanks :)